# java.awt.Robot equivalent in SWT

Tags: java, swt, swtbot

I am writing SWTBot tests for application, that has some components written in Delphi. Naturally, I am not able to handle these components via SWTBot. I found a workaround, I just set focus to the view or editor that contains the delphi component. Then I use `java.awt.Robot` to generate events that allow me to interact with the component.

I was just wondering, is there any tool in SWT, that would be able to do same things as `java.awt.Robot`? I haven't found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, there is nothing like it. More I think about it, more stupid it looks to me to duplicate common code to be framework specific

Answer (score 0):

You can automate GUI events in SWT by posting user-interface events using `Display.post`. This was implemented in 2004. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15025